# Why is f'{{{74}}}' the same as f'{{74}}' with f-Strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, formatting, f-string

[f-Strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) are available from Python 3.6 and are very useful for formatting strings:

```
>>> n='you'
>>> f'hello {n}, how are you?'
'hello you, how are you?'
```

Reading more about them in [Python 3's f-Strings: An Improved String Formatting Syntax (Guide)](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). I found an interesting pattern:

> Note that using triple braces will result in there being only single braces in your string:
>
> ```
> >>> f"{{{74}}}"
> '{74}'
> ```
>
> However, you can get more braces to show if you use more than triple braces:
>
> ```
> >>> f"{{{{74}}}}"
> '{{74}}'
> ```

And this is exactly the case:

```
>>> f'{74}'
'74'

>>> f'{{74}}'
'{74}'
```

Now if we pass from two `{` to three, the result is the same:

```
>>> f'{{{74}}}'
'{74}'           # same as f'{{74}}' !
```

So we need up to 4! (`{{{{`) to get two braces as an output:

```
>>> f'{{{{74}}}}'
'{{74}}'
```

Why is this? What happens with two braces to have Python require an extra one from that moment on?

Comment: It may be illuminating to compare the outputs of `f"{{2+2}}"` and `f"{{{2+2}}}"`, which are `'{2+2}'` and `'{4}'` respectively

Comment: @Kevin great one. It is funny how `f'{2+2}'` returns 4, `f'{{2+2}}'` returns 2+2, `f'{{{2+2}}}'` ➝ {4}, `f'{{{{2+2}}}}'` ➝ {{2+2}} and so on. It makes sense but puzzles a bit on a first sight.

Comment: Put simply, it's because `f'{74}'` is the same as `f'74'`.

Comment: This isn't anything new with f-strings, good old `str.format` does this too.

Comment: @Peilonrayz How?  `"{74}".format(...)` would require a sequence with at least 74 elements.

Comment: @gerrit replace `74` with say `n` and it'll be plain as day that it uses the same mechanism.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I don't see any way how removing a pair of braces can produce the same result, without f-strings.

Comment: @gerrit Have you tried Konrad's examples with `str.format`? It's clearly the same `x = 74;'{{x}}'.format(x=x);'{{{x}}}'.format(x=x)` -> `'{x}'`, `'{74}'`.

Comment: @Peilonrayz With `str.format`, in one case the result is `'{x}'`, in the other case it's `'{74}'`.  In the question using f-strings, the result is `'{74}'` in both cases.

Comment: @gerrit Have you even read Konrad's answer...

Comment: @Peilonrayz Yes, and it is entirely clear to me and I have no further questions.  It's not the same between f-strings or `str.format`.

Comment: @gerrit Well done at proving to yourself something I didn't say. ‎

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Double braces escape the braces, so that no interpolation happens: `{{` ➝ `{`, and `}}` ➝ `}`. And `74` remains an unchanged string, `'74'`.

With triple braces, the outer double braces are escaped, same as above. The inner braces, on the other hand, lead to regular string interpolation of the value `74`.

That is, the string `f'{{{74}}}'` is equivalent to `f'{{ {74} }}'`, but without spaces (or, equivalently, to `'{' + f'{74}' + '}'`).

You can see the difference when replacing the numeric constant by a variable:

```
In [1]: x = 74

In [2]: f'{{x}}'
Out[2]: '{x}'

In [3]: f'{{{x}}}'
Out[3]: '{74}'
```